# Is a pentagon a surface?

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, surfaces, manifolds-with-boundary, compact-manifolds

My question arise since a pentagon is homeomorphic to a closed disc. This last one is a surface with boundary.

However, a pentagon has vertices, so it seems isn't a 2-manifold.

If you consider a pentagon without edges, it is a 2-manifold, however isn't compact, so isn't a surface.

So... any polygon is a surface?

Regards

Comment: But a triangle isn't a surface, right? A triangle isn't a 2-manifold, but his vertices/corners

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pentagon with boundary is a topological $2-$manifold with boundary, but it is not a smooth $2-$manifold with boundary. So, this depends what you mean by surface.

A pentagon with boundary is a compact topological surface (where we relax the smoothness condition), however it is not a smooth surface in the typical sense. It is, however, a smooth manifold with corners.

Comment: The pentagon can be a smooth manifold with boundary.

Comment: Surface = compact connected 2-smooth manifold. So a pentagon can't be a surface. However, the disc is homeomorphic and it is... How is it possible?

Comment: Because being a smooth manifold is preserved by diffeomorphism, not homeomorphism. Homeomorphisms can introduce corners and singularities.

Comment: Thanks Alekos, so a pentagon with corners is not a surface even it is homeomorphic a disc. Now, how a disc with boundary is a 2-smooth manifold? The points in the boundary doesn't have neighborhood homeomorphic to an open subset of real plane

Comment: This depends on your definition of surface: if you require it to be a smooth manifold, then indeed it is not a (smooth) surface.

Comment: But i didn't understand the phrase "smooth manifold with corners" at the final on your first answer. It's impossible, no?  Additionally, what is the typical definition of surface?

Comment: There is a formalization of smooth manifold with corners, which you can find for instance in Lee’s smooth manifolds book. Also: a surface can just be a topological 2-manifold. You might want compact and connected, as well.